# When does hooks update in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When does a hook update when using a setter? I can see it somehow must be async. Consider following sample it shows, that the hook does not update instantly. Do you await hooks (if yes how) if you need the value just after, or what is normal approach here?

https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-snyder-dv84c?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: depending on your actual use case the easiest solution is to use useEffect. Here's your updated sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-async-z81kv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `setIndex` call is asynchronous, you cannot use it in the alert call and expect the updated value.

Instead [I would use the `useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for any actions that depend on the new state value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  alert(index);
}, [index])

function increment() {
  setIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex + 1); // update based on previous value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The function to update the state are called asynchronously, thus the updated state won't get reflected immediately.

You can instead do the action when the state changes, and for that we have `useEffect` hook.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  function increment() {
    setIndex(prevState => prevState + 1);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    alert(index);
  }, [index]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{index}</div>
      <button onClick={() => increment()}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have updated your codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-async-cgvkx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)